# Does create-react-app remain useful for larger more complex apps or does it get in the way?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I've been using create-react-app to quickly setup and run projects while learning React.  Coming from Angular this has been very useful and has allowed me to focus on learning React rather than getting bogged down learning the ins and outs of Webpack, Babel and other aspects of the toolchain.

I will soon be starting on a "real" React project of considerable complexity and need to decide if I will continue to rely on create-react-app or if now is the time to get comfortable with Webpack.  I know create-react-app has some limitations like no CSS preprocessor that I would need to consider.

What I would like to know, especially from those with experience creating more complex React applications, is whether or not the abstraction provided by create-react-app is useful in a larger more complex application or if it starts to get in the way such that "eject"-ing is inevitable.

**Update**: Changed the title and tried to make the question a little more specific in an effort to get this question re-opened.  Having not gone through the process of developing a complex application with React, it's hard, if not impossible, to know if the abstraction that create-react-app provides is worth it when moving from learning and playing to actually building something meaningful.

Comment: `npm run eject` will give you webpack config with babel, so create-react-app is a fast start, but you have to learn webpack anyway

Comment: @SlawaEremkin If you don't know webpack, those scripts are going to look so alien! I'd suggest if in a quick project use create-react-app and on your free time learn webpack.

Comment: @SlawaEremkin It seems you are suggesting that ejecting is inevitable and thus needing to learn webpack, etc is inevitable.  If this is the case, I am inclined to invest the time to learn as I go rather than "eject" out of need at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest learning the webpack. Because, the create-react-app will drop in tons of packages which we don't use mostly. If you learn webpack and configuring it, you'll able to setup minimal project structure and packages as per your requirement.

Webpack is a great tool which we should be aware of whats happening with it. You can use create-react-app for getting started with react but to play with react you should learn webpack.

Beware of webpack versions, V3 is an awesome package and its documentation is stright forward.https://webpack.js.org/concepts/